# How to get Temporary Storage Directory in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, local-storage, flutter-dependencies

I am creating a video app. So it generates thumbnail for every video. I want to store these thumbnail in local Storage of device(only temporary). So I want to get temporary path/Directory in device, where thumbnail will be stored. But I want to delete those thumbnails from Storage when user closes the app.

If you know the answer please answer the Question.

Comment: you can use a package called path_provider its store on temp something you would prefer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider),

```
Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
String tempPath = tempDir.path;

Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
```